# CSS width animation doesn't work

Tags: css, animation

I tried everything but I have no idea why these animations don't work. can anybody help me?

```css
.link {
    float:right;
    clear:both;
    padding:30px;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Dosis;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    text-align:right;
}

.link:hover {
    width:100%;
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">Something</div>
<div class="link">about</div>
<div class="link">you</div>
<div class="link">makes</div>
<div class="link">me</div>
```

Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's overcomplicated but it seems that works :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).width();
    $(this).css({"width":value});
    $(this).hover(function(){
    $(this).css({"width":"100%"});
    },function(){
    $(this).css({"width":value});
    })
    })
});
```

```css
.link {
  width: auto;
   float:right;
    clear:both;
    padding:30px;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Dosis;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    text-align:right;
}

.link:hover {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">Something</div>
<div class="link">about</div>
        <div class="link">you</div>
        <div class="link">makes</div>
        <div class="link">me</div>
```

Comment: how do i do it without setting an initial value?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible without a bit of javascript because according to Transition description ,,CSS3 transitions allows you to change property values smoothly (from one value to another), over a given duration."

Answer (score 0):

Here you go....

```css
.link {
            float:right;
            clear:both;
            padding:30px;
            font-size:20px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            color: #333;
            font-family: Dosis;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            text-decoration:none;
            background: yellow;
            -webkit-transition-property: width; /* Safari */
            -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
            transition-property: width;
            transition-duration: 2s;
        }

        .link:hover {
             width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="link">Something</div>
        <div class="link">about</div>
        <div class="link">you</div>
        <div class="link">makes</div>
        <div class="link">me</div>
```

Comment: Yeah but I want the initial value to be auto, is it possible?

Comment: which value are you talking about

Answer (score 0):

You could transition min-width instead of width. You can only transition from one value to another, that's why transitioning between "auto" and "100%" doesn't work.

```css
.link {
    float:right;
    clear:both;
    padding:30px;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Dosis;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transition: min-width 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: min-width 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: min-width 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: min-width 1s ease-in-out;
    text-align:right;
    min-width:0;
}

.link:hover {
    min-width:100%;
    -webkit-transition: min-width 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: min-width 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: min-width 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: min-width 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">Something</div>
<div class="link">about</div>
<div class="link">you</div>
<div class="link">makes</div>
<div class="link">me</div>
```